# Help with table alignment and spacing

Tags: tables

I am trying to make a table in latex.
But I'm not able to center what I write in the header and later I also wanted to write in each block below some writing and that this is not all in the same line (if you understand me).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\listoftables

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{Exemplos de Modelos de Previsão de Tráfego}
    \label{tab:hla:modelos}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lllllll}
       \toprule
         \multicolumn{1}{c}{\parbox{1cm}{\centering\textbf{Paper}}} & \parbox{1cm}{\centering\textbf{Método}} & \parbox{2cm}{\centering\textbf{Fonte\\de\\Dados}} & \parbox{2cm}{\centering\textbf{Parâmetros\\de\\ Entrada}} & \parbox{2cm}{\centering\textbf{Horizonte\\de\\Previsão}} & \parbox{2cm}{\centering\textbf{ Período\\de\\ Estudo}} \\
        \midrule
        \cite{Beckman08}    & ANN & GPS,Detetor de Veículos,Base de dados de incidentes & Velocidade, Volume,Ocupação,Data& Long-term 1 day Short-term 15 min & 1 \\
        \cite{Artho03}      & 1 & 4 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        \cite{Artho03}      & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        \cite{Artho03}      & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        \cite{Artho04}      & 1 & 4 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        \cite{Artho04}      & 0 & 7 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
        \cite{Artho04}      & 0 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
        \cite{Flanagan04}   & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
        \cite{Praun03}      & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        \cite{Praun03}      & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\vspace{1cm}

\end{document}
```

and this is the output after write in column:
[image]
 before write:
[image]

Comment: any news? do any of received answers help you?

Answer (score 2):

like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\small}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\newcommand\mcx[1]{\multicolumn{1}{L}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{Exemplos de Modelos de Previsão de Tráfego}
    \label{tab:hla:modelos}
    \centering
    \small
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} lc cc c c @{}}%ll ll l
       \toprule
\thead[b]{Paper}
    &   \thead[b]{Método}
        &   \thead[b]{Fonte\\de Dados}
            &   \thead[b]{Parâmetros\\de Entrada}
                &   \thead[b]{Horizonte\\de Previsão}
                    &   \thead[b]{Período\\de  Estudo}  \\
        \midrule
\cite{Beckman08}
    &   ANN
        &   \mcx{GPS, Detetor de Veículos, Base de dados de incidentes }
            &   \mcx{Velocidade, Volume, Ocupação, Data}
                &   \mcx{Long-term 1 day Short-term 15 min}
                                    & 1 \\
\cite{Artho03}      & 1 & 4 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\cite{Artho03}      & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\cite{Artho03}      & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\cite{Artho04}      & 1 & 4 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\cite{Artho04}      & 0 & 7 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
\cite{Artho04}      & 0 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
\cite{Flanagan04}   & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
\cite{Praun03}      & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\cite{Praun03}      & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `tabularx`, and `makecell` to simplify the code of the column headers. Also, `caption` to have a decent vertical spacing between caption and table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{caption, booktabs, tabularx, makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\listoftables
\vspace{1cm}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{Exemplos de Modelos de Previsão de Tráfego}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
    \label{tab:hla:modelos}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cc*{3}{ >{\centering}X}c}
       \toprule
         \thead{Paper} & \thead{Método} & \thead{Fonte\\de Dados} & \thead{Parâmetros\\de Entrada} & \thead{Horizonte\\de Previsão} & \thead{Período\\de Estudo}\\
        \midrule
        \cite{Beckman08} & ANN & \RaggedRight GPS, Detetor de Veículos, Base de dados de incidentes & \RaggedRight Velocidade, Volume, Ocupação, Data & \RaggedRight Long-term 1 day Short-term 15 min & 1 \\
        \cite{Artho03} & 1 & 4 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        \cite{Artho03} & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        \cite{Artho03} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        \cite{Artho04} & 1 & 4 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        \cite{Artho04} & 0 & 7 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
        \cite{Artho04} & 0 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
        \cite{Flanagan04} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
        \cite{Praun03} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        \cite{Praun03} & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In this case i have a problem write in last column

Comment: Which problem exactly?